# jqGrid - Grouping fields in edit form

Tags: jqgrid, grouping, edit, categories

It is possible to group some fields in the edit form?

I would like to group some fields together, give them a summarizing name and give the group some different background color and maybe even border so the user can navigate more easily.

Suppose I have 4 entries in the colModel:

```
name
address
title
income
```

I would like to show it in the edit form like:

```
Personal:----------
| name     [    ] |
| address  [    ] |
-------------------
Business:----------
| title    [    ] |
| income   [    ] |
-------------------
```

where the fields belonging to the Personal group/category would have - let's say - light green background and fields in the Business group would have light red background.

The difficulty is that there are lots of fields and I wouldn't want to give them background color on a one-by-one basis.
And if there are groups then I could even use some collapse jQuery plugin to let the user to hide some of the groups.

Right now I'm struggling with custom_element creating some table around the group but no success yet.

---

### Solution

As **Tony** pointed out on the [jQuery Grid help forum:](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/grouping-fields-in-edit-form/)

> Currently this feature is not available or at last adding such functionality requiere to use fsome events and knowledge of the structure of the edit form.
>
> We plan in the next major release to introduce a templating in  form editing.

So now there is no other solution like the one proposed by **Oleg** (thanks for the quick reply:).

I solved (partially) my task using his idea. Adding hrule containing table rows in the edit form, and finally styling the lines one-by-one.

The relevant parts:

```
$('<tr class="FormData"><td class="CaptionTD ui-widget-content" colspan="2"><hr/></td></tr>').insertBefore('#tr_********,');
$("#tr_*******,#tr_*******").css("background-color","#def");
```

Where the `*******` are the column names from the colModel.

Adding borders and making it collapsible is way too much fuss this way, so that will be skipped for now.

Comment: Did you check out their Demos? http://www.trirand.net/demophp.aspx
There is a section called grouping with quite several examples on the topic

Comment: Yes I checked them. Those sections about grouping refer to grouping in the grid itself. What I want is grouping in the add/edit form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is almost free modifying of Add or Edit form inside of [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) callback. I demonstrate the idea on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomFormEdit2.htm) which I quickly made for you. The example shows just an example of what you can do:

[image]

The corresponding code is

```js
$.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
    recreateForm: true,
    beforeShowForm: function($form) {
       $('<tr class="FormData"><td class="CaptionTD ui-widget-content" colspan="2">' +
           '<hr/><div style="padding:3px" class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">' +
           '<b>Invice information (all about money):</b></div></td></tr>')
           .insertBefore('#tr_amount');
       $('<tr class="FormData"><td class="CaptionTD ui-widget-content" colspan="2">' +
           '<hr/><div style="padding:3px" class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">' +
           '<b>Delivery information:</b></div></td></tr>')
           .insertBefore('#tr_closed');
    }
});
```

I set `$.jgrid.edit` only to change `beforeShowForm` for both "Add" in "Edit" forms. The `'amount'` and `'closed'` used in `.insertBefore('#tr_amount'))` and `insertBefore('#tr_closed')` are the column names from the `colModel`.

Comment: You're a superstar! Answering all the jqgrid questions like a pro!

Comment: @dtroy: Thanks! I'm glad that my answers helped you.