# codeigniter jqgrid add text to form

Tags: php, codeigniter, jqgrid

Using jqgrid with navigator to add/edit/delete in codeigniter. I want to add a simple text line to show within the form when it pops up. i've tried appending an html line in the beforeShowForm: to the form id and (separately) to the colmodel name but this places the html out side of the grid. How can i add this text? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't use codeigniter myself, but if you can define your `beforeShowForm` callback then you can add *rows* in the edit form. You can find examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10020340/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5745168/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8437659/315935).