# customizing jqgrid modal edit form

Tags: jqgrid

I found this demo of jqgrid that I am interested in using
[demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MulticolumnEdit.htm)

I have been reading the jqgrid wiki to determine if I can control the # of elements in the add form.

The parent grid shows 8 columns. In the modal form I only want to show 4 data entry elements as opposed to the 8 that are displayed in the demo.

Does jqgrid not allow this - meaning does it always display same # of data entry elements as there are # of columns displayed in the parent grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question you should add `editable: true` only to the column which will be ***ediatble***. Only the editable columns will be displayed in the Add/Edit form. If you need use multicolumn layout of edit form then you should use `rowpos` and `colpos` properties of [formoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#formoptions) like it is shown in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MulticolumnEdit.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852741/315935).

Comment: If i want to add elements, that are not part of the jqgrid, how do i customize the modal form?

Comment: @user1361914: Look at [the old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomFormEdit1.htm) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5745168/315935). Click on "Add" button. You will see manually added information. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10020340/315935) you will find another example.